# How to configure osquery with auditd

Tags: linux, audit, osquery

Who has expertise on how to work with osquery (or maybe you solved this problem):

Based on articles like this one - https://blog.palantir.com/auditing-with-osquery-part-two-configuration-and-implementation-87a8bba0ef48 I understand osquery can be used in conjunction with auditd rules in `auditd/audit.rules`. However, when I try to change in osquery.flags `--audit_allow_config=false` to use my rules, the process_events stop coming at all, although with the `--debug` option their registration is visible

Is it possible to log osquery all syscalls like auditd? So far only `execve` is visible in process_events

I use config and flags file from https://github.com/palantir/osquery-configuration/tree/master/Classic/Servers/Linux

Thank you in advance!